# How to update XCode 4.3.2 Compiler

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am getting strange warnings in xcode and from what I have read they mean I have to update my compiler to a CLANG based one. However I am not sure how to do this.

My question is how do I update my compiler to a ClANG compiler.

[image]

Comment: Are you getting a project update warning?  That's the easiest way to fix it.

Comment: I got the warning update.. but its updated it to a weird version LLVM GCC 4.2 which is causing my xcode to crash when I try to compile my app...

Comment: I have obviously done something wrong.. so frustrating.

Comment: oh. LOL dangit.. well then I have a bunch of errors saying **Expected a property attribute before 'strong'**

Comment: Is this by any chance an issue with updating to ARC? There are some differences you'll need to look into.

Comment: nope. I am not getting any arc issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'll you are using the CLANG compiler if you are using LLVM because CLANG is an LLVM front-end.

EDIT: The old CLANG+GCC 4.2 does NOT support ARC, only LLVM versions since summer 2011. Switch to LLVM only and run again.

Comment: No my compiler source list is completely up to date. I just triple checked it.

Comment: Well, that last comment of yours seems like it'll fix the majority of the errors.

Comment: no. I still have about 84 errors all saying "Expected a property attribute  before 'strong' I am trying to figure out how to fix them..

Comment: Yeah, you're using an old version of GCC then.  Look under 'Compiler Version' in build settings.

Comment: I cannot find compiler version under build settings.. I can only see it under build options in build settings. I have an image in my question showing you what I can see.

Comment: okay So I selected that, and I have reverted back to my original problem. When I try to run my application xcode stops responding and my simulator only half loads but never completes.

Comment: I posted the solution to this on your second to last question.